# Centering case-defined functions in the middle of the page and centering a figure(diagram)

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, cases

I have two questions regarding centering:

1. I am trying to center a case-defined function, say defined as follows:

   ```
   $f_i(z)=$  \begin{cases}\frac{1}{t}dist (z,\gamma_i ) &\text {if} z\in  A_i(t)\\ 
                                    1 &\text{if} z \in A_i \backslash A_i(t)\\  
                                    0 & \text{if} z \in  \tilde{M} \backslash A_i\\
             \end{cases}
   ```

   How do I center it?
2. Say the name of the figure I am inserting is 'egnpic', and I am using the following command to insert it in my LaTeX document:

   ```
       \hspace{11 mm} \includegraphics[height=100mm]{egnpic}\Apparently I am not seeing any effect of using `\hspace{11 mm}`, the relative position of the figure {egnpic} remains the same when I use `\hspace{5 mm}` and when I use `\hspace{11 mm}`.
   ```

Answer (score 3):

For the first question: You should enclose your equation inside a `equation*` or `align*` environment (assuming that you don't want to number them). If you need numbers, remove `*`.

Second question: You can use the `center` environment. Please remember that at the beginning of the line `\hspace{<len>}` is not effective. You should use `\hspace*{<len>}`.

However, if you are using a `figure` environment, it is better to use `\centering` than `center` environment as shown in the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe} %% Remove this, just for showing the centering effect

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
f_i(z)=  \begin{cases}\frac{1}{t}\ \mathrm{dist}(z,\gamma_i ) &\text {if } z\in  A_i(t)\\
                                 1 &\text{if } z \in A_i \backslash A_i(t)\\
                                 0 & \text{if } z \in  \tilde{M} \backslash A_i\\
          \end{cases}
\end{align*}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=100mm]{example-image-a} 
\end{center}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=100mm]{example-image-a}
\caption[short caption]{Long cation}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please note that, I have used `width` (instead of `height`) in `\includegraphics` command.